# SELECT query not working is pgrouting

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting

I was just going through this tutorial **[HERE](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/advanced.html#weighted-costs)**, its about pgrouting and basically when i run the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM types ORDER BY id;
```

I get an error saying `SELECT: command not found`, in the documentation the following is said:

> **Note**
>   We switch now to the database we previously generated with
>   osm2pgrouting. From within PostgreSQL shell this is possible with the
>   \c routing command.

now when i run the command  `\c routing` from my terminal i get the following error:

```
c: command not found
```

Well so to sum up my difficulty, how do i get the select query working ?

**[SCREENSHOT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz4Gz.png)**

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Comment: Before you can work with pgrouting, you need at least a basic PostgreSQL / psql experience. Try this tutorial:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial.html

Comment: @TommasoDiBucchianico , that was very kind of you thanks ! :)

Comment: You quit the psql with `\q` that's selects don't work after that. Please be more careful where you run your commands, you can hurt a server.

Comment: @JakubKania hurt a server ???

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Just kidding mostly. But, yeah, you run the commands not where you intended to, you can break something by accident.